# What do the words 'stationary and independent' mean in this instance?

Tags: stochastic-processes, time-series

Given $y_t=u_t+B_1(u_{t-1})+...+B_k(u_{t-k})=B(L)u_t$, a matrix MA(infinity) process

Response of the $i$'th element of matrix $y_t(y_t)^i$ to a unit shock to $j$'th element of $u_{t-k}$ is given by the coefficient $(b_k)^{ij}$ which is the $i,j\,$th element of the matrix $B_k$. 
$$
\frac{d(y_t)^i}{d(u_{t-k})^j}=(b_k)^{ij}
$$
The assumption on $u_t$ is that they are stationary and independent, which would imply that we can write the above expression as 
$$
\frac{d(y_{t+k})^i}{d(u_t)^j}=(b_k)^{ij}
$$
If you plot $(b_k)^{ij}$ as a function of $k$, you get the impulse response function (IRF)

Comment: Consider using mathjax

Comment: Can I have access to the automatic format change that this forum sometimes seems to offer? Last time I was fortunate enough to have that. I don't know anything about mathjax, unfortunately.

Comment: See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to use mathjax. I have fixed your formatting somewhat; please ensure it's ok (and look at the code to see how its done)!